# Highest possible pyramid

Tags: algorithm, logic, 2d

I tried everything, but I still can't solve this problem without brute force:
I get N blocks with a known height and width. I can rotate them (height become width and width become height) and I have to build the tallest possible pyramid from them (of course I can change the order of blocks).
The problem is that you can't put a block of width X onto a block with width smaller than X.

**EDIT:**
The problem is, that you can't put a block onto a block of the same width.


Any ideas?

Comment: If the blocks can directly be stacked on each other (without any constraints), then iterate over them and sum(max(block.height, block.width)) and it will be the maximum possible height. Which is a linear algorithm, you can't do any better since you need to inspect every block... or your question is something else entirely?

Comment: @AlekseiMaide The problem is that you can't put a block of width X onto a block with a width smaller than X.

Comment: Your question seems unclear. Would you please show brute force code you did and provide some testcases for expected input/output.

Comment: Could you provide the definition of pyramid, how could we know that the pyramid is valid? Any constraints for N?

Comment: @PhamTrung You can't put a block of width X onto a block with a width smaller than X.

Comment: So you mean each layer can only contain one block? @georgeel, how about the size of N? how large can N be?

Comment: There is a DP solution for the 3d case which runs in O(n^2) . In this problem you can reuse a box if you rotate it. Maybe you can get some ideas from there. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/box-stacking-problem-dp-22/

Comment: Ask yourself, would you ever lay a rectangle on its longer side?

Comment: Let `Height > Width` for each block (rotate blocks if necessary). Order by blocks by their width, stack them in this order into pyramid

Comment: This question, as asked, is too easy.  I think you've probably made a mistake in transcribing it.

Comment: I see much ambiguity in here so: What is the pyramid shape? you always put 1 block on 2 others? must the 2 support blocks be the same size? or there is gap possible ? or you can combine one of the blocks from more smaller ones placed on top of each to match the height of the other block? or you can combine both support blocks? what are the constraints in such case? like how many block cane be combined into single one ? What is the input? how much blocks, how much different sizes? etc so we can generate  a proper generator for testing ?

Comment: in case you are placing your block on a single block than I would not call that a pyramid ... more like tower ...

Answer (score 4):

What I understand reading your problem statement and comments is that you want to build tallest pyramid with `width` from bottom to top in decreasing order.
If this is the case, then what we can do is simply the following steps:

1. Loop over blocks and swap `width` and `height` only if `width > height`.
2. Now, sort the array of blocks in decreasing order of width which is the order used for stacking blocks from bottom to top in pyramid.
3. Answer is summation of all heights.

> Note: step -2 is only needed if you want to display order of blocks
>   from bottom to top in pyramid.

Comment: So the first stage is to rotate blocks making them "higher than wider" ??

Comment: @MBo, yes. First step ensure taller pyramid.

Comment: @BishalGautam The problem is, that you can't put a block onto a block of the same width.